# Deserializing JSON with this curly braces embedded in a string

Tags: c#, json, .net

One of the nodes in this JSON payload is driving me nuts.

It's formatted like a string (inside quotes), but it will not go into a string on my object.

Here is the entire payload just as I receive it:

```
{
    "Event_Id":"da89afe72b41cb685f03261d8cb18d9e",
    "Event_Name":"Employee Created",
    "Event_DateTime":1655144130,
    "ClientCode":"XXXXX",
    "Resource_Field":"Employee",
    "Resource_Identifier":null,
    "Object":null,
    "Object_Identifier":"9995",

    "Data":"{"Employee_ID":"9995","Is_Rehire":"N","Was_New_Hire":"Y"}",

    "Endpoint":"Employee",
    "EndpointUrl":"api/v1/employee/9995"
}
```

The problem is the `"Data"` property, separated it for clarity.

And here is the object that it loads to:

```
public class OutsideEvent
{
    public string Event_Id { get; set; }
    public string Event_Name { get; set; }
    public int Event_DateTime { get; set; }
    public string ClientCode { get; set; }
    public string Resource_Field { get; set; }
    public object Resource_Identifier { get; set; }
    public object Object { get; set; }
    public string? Object_Identifier { get; set; }

    **public string? Data { get; set; }**

    public string Endpoint { get; set; }
    public string EndpointUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Using Postman, I can remove the quotes from around the "Data" value, change the type to object and deserialize it into this:

```
public class eventData
{
    public string Employee_ID { get; set; }
    public string Is_Rehire { get; set; }
    public string Was_New_Hire { get; set; }
}
```

But I can't make the sender remove the quotes, so I have to deal with it somehow?

Also tried decorating the `Data` property with `[JsonIgnore]` since I don't care about this value, but it didn't change anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume the two double asterixes are not actually part of the file, but just put there for our benefit, highlighting the problematic part. If, however, the rest of the file is *exactly* like this, then this is not valid JSON, pure and simple. Specifically, the double quotes in that string should be escaped, you should have something like this: `"Data":"{\"Employee_ID\":\"9995\",\"Is_Rehire\":\"N\",\"Was_New_Hire\":\"Y\"}"`

Comment: Yeah I thought those * would make it Bold :)

Comment: Look at the answer provided from Serge below, it shows an alternate way of viewing your problem, basically stop treating it like a string and move the braces outside of the string, that way you have an actual JSON object there. In other words, you would have `"Data": {"Employee_ID":"9995", ... :"Y"}`, since the braces are now not enclosed in strings, they form the start and end of a json object instead. This is probably the simplest way of handling it.

Comment: You need to fix whatever is generating invalid JSON in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

json data property is an invalid string, since it contains double quotes included in double quotes

```
....
"Data":"{"Employee_ID":"9995","Is_Rehire":"N","Was_New_Hire":"Y"}",
....
```

so just remove outer double quotes, you can do it using string replace function

```
    json = json.Replace("\"{", "{").Replace("}\"","}");
```

now you have a valid json

```
...
"Data":{"Employee_ID":"9995","Is_Rehire":"N","Was_New_Hire":"Y"},
....
```

and you can deserialize it to c#

```
    Root root=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

Classes

```
public class Data
{
    public string Employee_ID { get; set; }
    public string Is_Rehire { get; set; }
    public string Was_New_Hire { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public string Event_Id { get; set; }
    public string Event_Name { get; set; }
    public int Event_DateTime { get; set; }
    public string ClientCode { get; set; }
    public string Resource_Field { get; set; }
    public object Resource_Identifier { get; set; }
    public object Object { get; set; }
    public string Object_Identifier { get; set; }
    public Data Data { get; set; }
    public string Endpoint { get; set; }
    public string EndpointUrl { get; set; }
}
```